# RabbitMQ disconnect me after some time

Tags: python, queue, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I'm trying to constantly listen for the queue, but after about a minute (assuming my queue is empty ) I got disconnected with this error:

```
DEBUG:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Outbound buffer size: 0
DEBUG:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Outbound buffer size: 0
ERROR:pika.adapters.base_connection:Read empty data, calling disconnect
DEBUG:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Handling disconnect
INFO:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:on_connection_closed: None, True
WARNING:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Received Channel.Close, closing: None
DEBUG:pika.callback:Clearing out '1' from the stack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controller.py", line 59, in <module>
    c.run()
  File "controller.py", line 55, in run
    self.listen_queue() # Blocking function
  File "controller.py", line 25, in listen_queue
    self.channel.start_consuming() # Start consuming
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 814, in start_consuming
    self.connection.process_data_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 168, in process_data_events
    if self._handle_read():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 272, in _handle_read
    super(BlockingConnection, self)._handle_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 315, in _handle_read
    return self._handle_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 263, in _handle_disconnect
    self._on_connection_closed(None, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 321, in _on_connection_closed
    self._channels[channel]._on_close(method_frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 914, in _on_close
    raise exceptions.ChannelClosed(0, 'Not specified')
pika.exceptions.ChannelClosed: (0, 'Not specified')
```

And this is my code:

```
class RabbitConnector():

    def __init__(self):
        self._connect()

    def _connect(self):
        logger.info('Trying to connect to RabbitMQ')
        while True:
            try:
                conn_broker = pika.BlockingConnection(
                    pika.ConnectionParameters(
                        host=conf.rabbit_server,
                        port=conf.rabbit_port,
                        virtual_host=conf.rabbit_vhost,
                        ssl=conf.rabbit_ssl, # do not set it to True if there is no ssl!
                        heartbeat_interval=conf.rabbit_heartbeat_interval,
                        credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(
                            conf.rabbit_user,
                            conf.rabbit_pass)))
                logger.info('Successfully connected to Rabbit at %s:%s' % (conf.rabbit_server, conf.rabbit_port)) 
                self.channel = conn_broker.channel()
                # Don't dispatch a new message to a worker until it has processed and acknowledged the previous one
                self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=conf.rabbit_prefetch_count)
                status = self.channel.queue_declare(queue=conf.rabbit_queue_name,
                                                    durable=conf.rabbit_queue_durable,
                                                    exclusive=conf.rabbit_queue_exclusive,
                                                    passive=conf.rabbit_queue_passive)
                if status.method.message_count == 0:
                    logger.info("Queue empty")
                else:
                    logger.info('Queue status: %s' % status)                  
                self.channel.queue_bind(
                    queue=conf.rabbit_queue_name,
                    exchange=conf.rabbit_exchange_name,
                    routing_key=conf.rabbit_exchange_routing_key)  
            except (pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError, pika.exceptions.AMQPChannelError), e:
                time.sleep(3)
                logger.error('Exception while connecting to Rabbit %s' %e)
            else:
                break

    def get_channel(self):
        return self.channel
```

Comment: I also got this error, which is not what I want or expect. I am going to try the synchronous version of polling the queue instead of the basic_consume & start_consuming idiom.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the `heartbeat_interval`, to a smaller number, e.g. 25 (seconds).
Based on https://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2013-March/025824.html

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue when queue was left empty for some time. Connection was lost. It was an issue with firewall. Check your firewall rules for connection IP

Comment: what issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue in my project. I have tried asking this in their forum but no satisfied solutions.
So, now I am just checking the channel and the connection is alive every time before sending the data. If not, then just reconnect and then send.

Maybe you can try this.

Comment: This is a valid solution that I have implemented in our project. It is one of the workarounds that one can try.